# Terraform - Is there a best practice for managing AMIs used in launch configurations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ami

At my work we've inherited kind of an archaic, janky Terraform structure and procedure. For the sake of time lets just say it's too much work to fix or start from scratch right this second. I'm also pretty new to Terraform and don't know a lot of best practices.

Basically our issue right now is, we spin up a lot of AMIs as part of our builds and deployments. We want to make sure we keep the AMIs that are currently being used as part of a launch configuration, but we also want to remove older ones once the launch configurations are replaced as part of a new deployment. At the moment, we replace the launch configurations and the old AMIs just sit there, pretty indistinguishable from the new ones because the LCs all have unique names and they don't match the AMI names, which use the build number in TeamCity.

Is there a best practice for deregistering these AMIs when they are no longer needed? Is there any way to remove AMIs once they are not used in a LC, or maybe tag them so they can be removed by an automated process later? How do people manage these generally?

Answer (score 0):

AMI servers as a backup from which you can launch new instances. The definition of "un-used" AMI is use-case specific, and there is no per-defined notion of what not used ami is.

For some it could be AMI which is older then 1 month, for other it can be ami that has not been used in a instance for a week, and for you it maybe AMI not associated with current versions of your LCs.

Thus, you would have design your own solution that would identify such AMIs. It could be in the form of a lambda function that executes periodically and compares your list of AMIs with those in your LCs.